# Why doesn't this lua pattern match remove the '.xml' including the .?

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

```
function getXMLBaseFileName(filename)
  try = filename:match("^(.+)\.xml$")
  if try == nil then
      return filename
  else
      return try
  end
end
```

When given a file name like "foo.xml" i will return "foo." so including the dot, but that is outside of the () pair.

Comment: Your code utterly fails when I try it: `invalid escape sequence near '\.'`

Comment: The OP is probably using Lua 5.1 when any char can be escaped; the escape is ignored if it doesn't make sense. This has changed in Lua 5.2+.

Answer (score 5):

The code you posted doesn't compile, because `\.` is not a valid Lua string escape sequence. You're trying to escape the `.` character incorrectly; you need to use a *pattern* escape, not a Lua string escape. Specifically, `"^(.+)%.xml$"`. Once you do that, your code works fine.

Comment: Silly me. That's what you get when working in 3 languages at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

```lua
function getXMLBaseFileName(filename)
   return (filename:gsub("%.xml$", ""))
   -- www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub
end

print(getXMLBaseFileName('foo.xml'))
```

:)

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @ArdentCoder There's little I could add beyond the documentation of the [`gsub`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub) function, which can easily be read in the reference manual.

Comment: This turned up in low quality posts, I've not recommended deletion because of your rep and I know you'll take the comment positively. So I guided you to improve this post; maybe you could add a link to the reference which you're talking about into your answer.